# Unable to run a LWC Jest test for a custom LWC that uses lightning-quick-action-panel or CloseActionScreenEvent

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I get this error:

> Cannot find module 'lightning/quickActionPanel'

when running this Jest test:

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import DuplicateScreenAction from 'c/duplicateScreenAction';

let componentElement = null;

describe('DuplicateScreenAction', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        componentElement = createElement('c-duplicateScreenAction', {
            is: DuplicateScreenAction
        });
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    it('component created', () => {
        document.body.appendChild(componentElement);
        expect(componentElement).not.toBe(null);
    });
});
```

where the `duplicateScreenAction` custom LWC HTML includes [lightning-quick-action-panel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-quick-action-panel/documentation) which is documented as **beta**. The component works fine in the product desktop. Other Jest tests work fine.

Am I missing something here e.g. are beta components excluded from [LWC Jest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/testing)?

I have run `sfdx update` and `npm update`.

**PS**

I get a similar error for this:

```
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
```

Background info here [Create Screen Quick Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you ran `npm update`, your `sfdx-lwc-jest` node dependency must point to an older version. Your `package.json` will show this within `devDependencies` (I ran into a similar issue).

If you update your version to the most recent listed [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest) within your `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^1.0.0",
    ...
}
```

and then run `npm install`, that should solve your issue as it'll get you the latest jest version.

For background, LWC quick action panel is GA in [Summer '21](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_quick_actions.htm&type=5&release=232) and, if you take a peek at the [jest repo](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/tree/master/src/lightning-stubs/quickActionPanel), you can see they added the stubs for `lightning-quick-action-panel` within this [PR](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/pull/206/files).

There's even example jest tests for LWC quick actions in the [lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/dispatchEventHeadlessAction/__tests__/dispatchEventHeadlessAction.test.js) and one utilizing [CloseActionScreenEvent](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/editRecordScreenAction/__tests__/editRecordScreenAction.test.js) as well.

Comment: Yep mine was set to 0.10.4. Thanks for the very clear and helpful answer!

Comment: After the version change, I've run into "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined" which is an undefined `options` value being passed through to a `crypto` reference. Presume you didn't hit that?

Comment: I didn't, but that error seems to be referenced in this [issue](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/issues/239). There's a [PR](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/pull/240) referenced to fix it, but hasn't been merged yet.

Comment: Thanks again Kris; I'll watch out for a new version.

Comment: @KeithC, looks like the PR closed (version 1.0.1) and that should fix that error you saw.